# Can't execute macro - Error '76' path not found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not really familiar with VB macros. I keep getting

> error '76' path not found.

Below is a sample of the code. The thing is we have a file with a macro that is going to sit on a synced OneDrive location. The OneDrive location unfortunately depend's on the user's profile. I tried `%username%` but it won't work unless I indicate my exact username. This is not what I want as multiple users will be using the macro-enabled file from their respective OneDrive locations. Any ideas?

```
Sub Export_XML()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim output As String

    For Each r In Range("XML_Output").Rows
        output = output & r.Value & vbNewLine
    Next r

    Open "C:\Users\%username%\Brand Developers Limited\Media Scheduling - 9. SpreeTV\Spree.xml" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close

    MsgBox "Spree schedule export complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel doesn't know anyting about `%username%`. You need to expand that yourself and use the actual path. A search for how to **Get** **env**ironmental variables in VBA should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
Open "C:\Users\" & environ("username") & "\Brand Developers Limited\Media Scheduling - 9. SpreeTV\Spree.xml" For Output As #1
```